# How to add/update a reference object in firestore admin with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm learning about Cloud Firestore (coding on Nodejs/Express - restfull api)
I have two collections:

- Users

  - username
  - email
  - password
- Restaurants

  - title
  - address
  - content
  - createdBy (example: reference object Users/UwxCkzuV2if1icGowsT6 )

I donot know how to add a reference object User to Restaurant.
Can you help me to add the code in the section below?
And can you recommend me some articles about CURD with reference objects?

Thank you.

```
async createRestaurant(req, res, next) {
    try {
      //debugApp(req.body);
      let { error } = Restaurant.validateRestaurant(req.body);
      if (error) return next(ApiError.invalid_400());

      const { title, content, address } = req.body;
      console.log("creating a Restaurant.......");
      //----------------------------------------------------
      const restaurantsRef = db.collection("restaurants");
      const snapshot = await restaurantsRef.where("title", "==", title).get();

      if (!snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("duplicate_400");
        return next(ApiError.duplicate_400());
      }
      //----------------------------------------------------
      var userId = "UwxCkzuV2if1icGowsT6" //this is a example Id
      const response = await restaurantsRef.add({
        title: title,
        content: content,
        address: address,
        //How to add reference object createdBy: users/UwxCkzuV2if1icGowsT6
        //please add your code here. Thanks
        //createdBy: .......
      });
      //----------------------------------------------------
      console.log("created a Restaurant.......");
      const restaurantJSON = await restaurantDetailsToJSON(response.id);
      return ApiSuccess.send(res, { restaurant: restaurantJSON });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return next(
        ApiError.internal_500("This restaurant could not be created", err)
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The firebase `doc` function return a DocumentReference. *I tend to just save the documentId* as the reference. Because to reference that document is as simple as `db.collection("users").doc(userId)`. And fetching that document would be `await db.collection("users").doc(userId).get()`, which would return Snapshot

```
const response = await restaurantsRef.add({
    title: title,
    content: content,
    address: address,
    //How to add reference object createdBy: users/UwxCkzuV2if1icGowsT6
    //please add your code here. Thanks
    //createdBy: .......
    createdBy: db.collection("users").doc(userId)
  });
```

Firebase Code Documentation

```
/**
 * Get a `DocumentReference` for a randomly-named document within this
 * collection. An automatically-generated unique ID will be used as the
 * document ID.
 *
 * @return The `DocumentReference` instance.
 */
doc(): DocumentReference<T>;
```